# Is it possible to load an html file in site_prism?

Tags: ruby, site-prism

I would need to load an html as a SitePrism Object. Is this possible? From what I see in the documentation, you can only navigate using certain url's. Would I need to store the html in a relative path in my app and then load that url with site_prism? Or do you guys see other, cleaner way to do this?

Thanks!
Rodrigo J. Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean passing in a string that contains HTML for a page, no you can't. If you mean accessing a local file containing html, yes you can, as follows:

```
class Home < SitePrism::Page
  set_url "file:///Users/bob/Desktop/html/home.htm"
end
```